# Linked Lists Output

Tags: java, linked-list

I created a linked list, and some methods for it. I was tasked to create a list of names. In the main, the user is instructed to enter a name, and then the program sees if the name is located in the list. It does compile, but the only thing I can not figure out is how to print that the name was not found. Thank you for your help! here is my code

```
package linkedlists;
import java.util.*;

public class Link {

public String Name;
public Link next;

public Link(String Name){
    this.Name = Name;
}

public void display(){
    System.out.println("Name in List " + Name);
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return Name;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);


    LinkList theLinkedList = new LinkList();
    theLinkedList.insertFirstLink("James");
    theLinkedList.insertFirstLink("John");
    theLinkedList.insertFirstLink("Michael");
    theLinkedList.insertFirstLink("Peter");
    theLinkedList.insertFirstLink("Allison");
    theLinkedList.insertFirstLink("Daniel");
    theLinkedList.insertFirstLink("George");
    theLinkedList.insertFirstLink("Simon");
    theLinkedList.insertFirstLink("Jason");
    theLinkedList.insertFirstLink("Mark");

    System.out.print("Please enter a Name to search for");
    System.out.println();

    String name;
    name = input.nextLine();

    //System.out.println(theLinkedList.find(name).Name);

     if (theLinkedList.find(name).Name == null){
        System.out.println("Not Found");
        System.out.println();
        theLinkedList.display();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(theLinkedList.find(name).Name + " was found.");
        System.out.println();
        theLinkedList.display();

    }






    }

}
```

and this is the LinkList class
    class LinkList{ 
    public Link firstLink;

```
LinkList(){

    firstLink = null;

}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return (firstLink == null);

}

public void insertFirstLink(String Name){
    Link newLink = new Link(Name);
    newLink.next = firstLink;
    firstLink = newLink;
}

public Link removeFirst(){
    Link linkReference = firstLink;
    if (!isEmpty()){
        firstLink = firstLink.next;

    } 
    else {
      System.out.println("Empty Linked List");

    }
    return linkReference;
}

public void display(){

    Link theLink = firstLink;

    while (theLink != null){
        theLink.display();
        System.out.println("Next Name in List: " + theLink.next);
        theLink = theLink.next;
        System.out.println();             
    }

}

public Link find(String Name){
    Link theLink = firstLink;

    if(!isEmpty()){

        while(!(theLink.Name.equals(Name))){

            if(theLink.next == null){
                return null;

            } else {
                theLink = theLink.next;

            }

        }

    } else {

        System.out.println("Empty LinkedList");

    }

    return theLink;

}

public Link removeLink(String Name){
    Link currentLink = firstLink;
    Link previousLink = firstLink;

    while(currentLink.Name != Name){
        if (currentLink.next == null){
            return null;
        }
        else{
            previousLink = currentLink;
            currentLink = currentLink.next;

        }

    }
    if (currentLink == firstLink){
        firstLink = firstLink.next;
    }
    else { 
        System.out.println(" Found a match!");
        System.out.println("Current Link: " + currentLink);
        System.out.println("First Link: " + firstLink);

        previousLink.next = currentLink.next;

    }
    return currentLink;
    }

}
```

Comment: That logic looks ripe for a NullPointerException. When the list is empty, you return a null link. Then try to access the name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern for traversing a LinkedList generally remains the same.

1. Check if list is null -> Can return immediately
2. Store a reference to the first link
3. While there is any link left, continue on, else go-to `6`
4. Do some logic, returning when you meet some condition
5. Move the link, (go back to `4`)
6. The loop has ended, return the final state of the function

In code

```
public Link find(String Name){

    if(isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Empty LinkedList");
        return null;
    } 

    Link theLink = firstLink;
    while(theLink != null) {
        if (theLink.Name.equals(Name)) {
            return theLink;
        }

        theLink = theLink.next;
    }

     // looped through the whole list, didn't find anything
    return null;
}
```

Now, that's an iterative solution, but the more advanced solution is to write the same recursively

```
public Link find(String Name) {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Empty LinkedList");
        return null;
    } 
    return findRecur(firstLink, Name);
}

private Link findRecur(Link link, String Name){
    if (link == null) return null;
    if (link.Name.equals(Name)) return link;
    return findRecur(link.next, Name);
}
```

Either way, call with

```
final Link found = theLinkedList.find(name);
if (found == null){
    System.out.println("Not Found");
} else {
    System.out.println(found.Name + " was found.");
}
System.out.println();
theLinkedList.display();
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice and guidance! I really do appreciate it. I really appreciate showing how to do it by an iterative solution and the recursive solution!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line
  if (theLinkedList.find(name).Name == null){

with

if(null == theLinkedList.find(name)){

Your statement tried to get the Link object relating to the name entered but when the name entered is not in the list, null is returned rather than a Link object. It is sufficient to check that that the returned value is null from the find function to be sure that the name does not exist in the list. 
Your code attempted to operate  on the null Link object returned when the name did not exist - that will cause a null pointer exception as you must have seen.